# (key) field [@timestamp] not found

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash, kibana

Tried lots of configuration the last couple of days but can't get ELK properly up and running:

```
ES says Facet [0]: (key) field [@timestamp] not found
LS says Parse Failure [No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on]]
```

Posts saying Goto your dashboard->settings->index and replace [_all] with [logstash*] won't fix the problem. So first question would be: Where's the right place to search for solution - ES, LS or Kibana?

My current configuration looks like this:

**Versions**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- ES 1.1.1 LS 1.4.1
- Kibana 3 (not LS build in but running seperately)

**Kibana**

My Kibana dashboard index settings looks like:

*Timestamping: day*

*Index pattern: [logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD*

**LS**

- default.conf which is loaded at LS startup - with 2 words:
- Loading 2 files with same structure containing a timestamp, an UUID plus an integer value.

`

```
input {
  file {
    type => "registrations1"
    path   => [ "/opt/source/EU/A1/reg1/*.log" ]
    start_position => "beginning"
    discover_interval => 1
  }
  file {
    type => "registrations2"
    path   => [ "/opt/source/EU/A1/reg2/*.log" ]
    start_position => "beginning"
    discover_interval => 1
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "registrations1"
  {
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      drop { }
    }
    grok {
      patterns_dir => "/opt/logstash-1.4.1/patterns"
      match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{UUID:pat} %{NUMBER:cntpat:int}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "logdate", "ISO8601" ]
    }
  }
  if [type] == "registrations2"
  {
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      drop { }
    }
    grok {
      patterns_dir => "/opt/logstash-1.4.1/patterns"
      match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{UUID:inst} %{NUMBER:cntinst:int}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "logdate", "ISO8601" ]
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
}
```

`

Some sample entries of file type registrations1:

`2014-01-03T12:19:05.683 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 1
2014-01-03T14:51:22.690 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 1
2014-01-05T16:09:03.970 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003 1
2014-01-06T11:42:12.963 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004 1
2014-01-06T13:35:54.697 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005 1
2014-01-06T13:40:26.513 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006 1
2014-01-07T13:51:12.777 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000007 1
2014-01-07T14:19:37.620 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000008 1`

registrations2 entries are pretty much the same - with different timestamps and UUIDs.

registrations1 file contains 485 entries - only 213 (or sometimes 199) are shown in Kibana. Why? And yes, I already adjusted Kibana datetime picker + removed drop statement from default.conf.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Best,
Alex

Comment: Does your test on the grokparsefailure tag works as intended? It seems quite weird to me that you are already checking it before you actually begin to apply grok

Comment: Yes, seems to work. But I'll give a try and move it to the bottom of each if-block.